# Multiple list iteration and association of data from one to another

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have two ArrayLists -> one with String of labels, second with Objects which have a variable on which label can be set.
Size of both the Lists is same.
Is there a way to do this simultaneously and neatly in Java 8 using Stream API

I can do it by using for loop and setting them simultaneously but is there a better way to do using Streams APIs

```java
        List<Items> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0 ; i<11 ;i++)
            items.add(new Item());
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("2.11");
            add("2.12");
            add("2.10");
            add("2.1");
            add("1.1");
            add("1.1");
            add("1.0");
            add("2.12");
            add("1");
            add("1");
            add("2.01");
        }};
        for(int i=0;i <11 ; i++){
                   items.get(i).setLabel(labels.get(i));
        }
```

Every item object should have a label set based on the labels List.

Comment: No, using the Stream API won't make it better than what you have now. You should use the list size instead of hardcoding 11, though. You should also avoid creating an anonymous subclass of ArrayList just to populate it, and better format the code.

Comment: why don't you just use a Map instead of the list? Then you would be able to iterate through the map with key of type String and value of type Item. One collection = easy iteration

Comment: One loop is enough, add item and set label in the same loop. (It is a good culture to do so)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `IntStream.range()` to generate the range of indexes and using those indexs we can populate each item from the `items` List:

```
List<Item> list = IntStream.range(0, labels.size())
                                   .mapToObj(idx -> { Item item = items.get(idx); item.setLabel(labels.get(idx)); return item; })
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

We can also maintain a `final` `AtomicInteger` index counter to keep track of the `labels` list's index and finally use a custom `Collector`:

```
final AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger();
List<Item> result = items.stream()
                         .collect(ArrayList::new, 
                          (list, item) -> { item.setLabel(labels.get(idx.getAndIncrement())); 
                                            list.add(item);
                                          }, 
                          ArrayList::addAll);
```